# Cannot capture my UDP packages broadcasted to 255.255.255.255, but can see other's

Tags: java, udp

I have read the Q&A's about broadcasting and I got the general idea. However, when playing with my Java code, I am confused.

My IP address is 192.168.8.102. When I broadcast to 192.168.8.255, I can receive the package that from myself and have it captured on wireshark. But when I broadcast to 255.255.255.255, the wireshark seems missing it though my code still receives it. When I run someone else's app, the wireshark captures the package that it broadcasts to 255.255.255.255.

Any explainations? Much appreciated!

PS. here is part of my Java code:

```
DatagramSocket senderSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
senderSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
senderSocket.setBroadcast(true);
senderSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(2000));
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");
byte[] SendBuffer = contentSent.getBytes();

senderPacket = new DatagramPacket(SendBuffer, SendBuffer.length, address, 2000);
senderSocket.send(senderPacket);
```

Comment: Broadcasting to 255:255.255.255 has been deprecated for about 25 years.

Answer (score 0):

If your socket is not bound to a specific interface, packets send to 255.255.255.255 will be sent out on the default interface.  If that's not the one Wireshark is listening on, that explains why it doesn't see it but your code does.

If your socket is bound to a specific interface, that guarantees that sending on that socket goes out on that interface.

As EJP mentioned in the comments, broadcasting to 255.255.255.255 is not recommended, in part because of the limitation I mentioned.  You're better off using the broadcast address for the link in question, i.e. 192.168.8.255 in your case.